# Installation issue with tidyverse package

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-package

I am having trouble installing packages, I was not able to install any. I got the following error in my r console:

> ERROR: dependency 'cachem' is not available for package 'memoise'
> * removing 'C:/Users/VasquezV/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/memoise'
> Warning in install.packages :
> running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\VasquezV\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\VasquezV\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpuiYtO1/downloaded_packages/memoise_2.0.1.tar.gz' had status 1
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘memoise’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

The major issue with this problem is that the `cli` package might not be updated as it often shows 3.1.1 installed but 3.3.0 required. Hence you have two solutions:

1. `install.packages(cli)` - there are chances that even this step
   might fail as the error message is displayed: "Error in unpacking packages."
2. Uninstall Cran R and R studio and reinstall it or install the package for replacing the existing one to solve the issue.
   This will definitely work as I have solved the issue through this way itself.